# Is "time" needed in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, nouns, time

> I must remember to bath within ten minutes time.

Is the word "time" needed in this sentence, or is it superficial? Is it even wrong to remove it?

Comment: ("bathe", not "bath")

Comment: Idiot: do you mean "ten minutes' time"? If so, then I believe it to be grammatical...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two quantities 'minute' describes -

- very small angles
- time

It is clear from the context of the sentence that you're not talking about angles so 'time' is superfluous in this sentence. It *may* not be incorrect, but it certainly isn't 'native speaker' usage.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds wrong with "time" to me but I can't come up with evidence my feeling is correct. "In ten minutes time" is definitely correct and "Within ten minutes" is definitely correct.

Answer (score 1):

No, you shouldn't use "time" in this context.

You do something "within" a *period* of time, but "ten minutes time" denotes a *single point* in time.

Answer (score 0):

The expression is *ten minutes' time* (i.e., the time consumed by ten minutes), not *ten minutes time*. It's generally acceptable, but it's a bit idiomatic and I don't think adding the possessive plus "time" is ever strictly necessary.